# Ruby: data doesn't have quotation mark but CSV.parse raises CSV::MalformedCSVError: Illegal quoting in line x

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, csv

I'm using ruby CSV.parse to read live data from Google sheet for my Rails project.
In my seeds.rb file, I'm reading csv data like this

```
point_csv_path = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/{key}/gviz/tq?tqx=out:csv&sheet=points"
CSV.parse(open(point_csv_path), :headers=>true).each do |row|
   Point.create!(
      point_id: row["point_id"].to_i, 
      point_type: row["point_type"], 
      identifier: row["identifier"].to_i, 
      longitude: row["longitude"],
      latitude: row["latitude"],
      location: row["location"],
      ordering: row["ordering"].to_i)
end
```

For the data in google sheet,I manually copy and paste from online source and the data doesn't contain any quotation mark at all. The EXACT first 3 lines of data in the google sheet is the following:

```
point_id    point_type  identifier  longitude   latitude    location    ordering
1           sensor      1           -71.050054  42.360152   null        0
2           sensor      2           -71.049428  42.359373   null        0
3           sensor      3           -71.049337  42.358969   null        0
```

After I ran `$ rails db:seed`, I get the following error message

```
rails aborted!
CSV::MalformedCSVError: Illegal quoting in line 3.
/media/anyan/file/rails_project/db/seeds.rb:33:in `<main>'
/media/anyan/file/rails_project/bin/rails:9:in `<top (required)>'
/media/anyan/file/rails_project/bin/spring:15:in `<top (required)>'
bin/rails:3:in `load'
bin/rails:3:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => db:seed
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

I know there are a lot of similar questions on stackoverflow but none of them I tried solve my problem. For example, adding `:quote_char => "|"` or `:encoding => 'bom|utf-8'` as argument for CSV.parse(). I thought it was something related to reading csv data stream so I downloaded the data to disk and I have the same error. How can I solve this problem? Thanks!

UPDATE: after download csv file to local disk and open with VSCode, the first 3 lines of data is:

```
"point_id","point_type","identifier","longitude","latitude","location","ordering"
"1","sensor","1","-71.050054","42.360152","null","0"
"2","sensor","2","-71.049428","42.359373","null","0"
"3","sensor","3","-71.049337","42.358969","null","0"
```

Comment: Would be helpful to see *exactly* what the first few lines of data look like.

Comment: Open the csv in something like sublime text editor. I had the same issue when import csvs. Postgres does not handle null bytes. If the files were exported from MSSQL or something that treats nulls as null bytes it could give error. Sublime will be able to show the `<0x00> ` byte. It will also show any `?` errors in ecoding. Another thing to try is set encoding when reading the CSV file. But first need to fix the null byte. Also, if the encoding of the file is binary, that will negate any encoding changes that postgres can do

Comment: Did you try to set col_sep to comma or tab? Another problem could be the line end handling (CR/LF).